# Cannot get session value in another controller

Tags: controllers, session, core-session

I am trying to get the session value in another controller but don't get value from the session:

```
class Vaibhav_User_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
  {
    public function loginAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $model = Mage::getModel('user/user')->load($data['login']['username'],'email');
    if($model->getPassword() == $data['login']['password'])
    {

        if($model->getUserType() == 2)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setLogiusername($model->getUserId());
            $this->_redirect('user/vendor/index');
            return ;
        }
    }
    else{
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Invalid Email Id or Password.');
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        return;
    }
}
}




class Vaibhav_User_VendorController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function preDispatch() 
    {

    }
    public function indexAction()
{
    echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLogiusername();
    exit;
}
}
```

Comment: In which order/context are those controllers called?

Comment: Edit question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set session  using this code

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
$session->setData("user_id", $userid);
```

and then get session using this code

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("core/session",  array("name"=>"frontend"));
echo $Value= $session->getData("user_id");
```